# TYPO3 6.2 tx_news details urls with parameters get thrown to 404 page

Tags: php, .htaccess, typo3-6.2.x, realurl, tx-news

I've a typo3 website which is using Typo3 6.2.15. I've an extension "mmc_directmail_subscription" for newsletter subscription which is rendered in all the pages. I am using tx_news in my website and in news detail page, when I click on subscribe button it is redirecting to 404 page.

The url like this `http://www.example.com/test/news.html?tx_mmcdirectmailsubscription_subscr[action]=register&tx_mmcdirectmailsubscription_subscr[contoller]=Subscribe`.

I've added "cHashExcludedParameters" based on the comment [TYPO3 6.1.7 news details urls with parameters get thrown to 404 page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22450764/typo3-6-1-7-news-details-urls-with-parameters-get-thrown-to-404-page) in install tool like this;

> $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE'][cHashExcludedParameters] =
>   L,tx_mmcdirectmailsubscription_subscr[action],tx_mmcdirectmailsubscription_subscr[contoller]

But this is not working. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Hey, did you manage to solve this? I'm having the same issue, but on 7.6

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is on chash added. You can disable this feature by deactivating `[FE][pageNotFoundOnCHashError]` in the Install Tool